# Web Part connection does not work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, connected-web-parts

I have a custom list view, and when I add the Web Part and try to connect it says "No Schema Provider".

If I do this in a unique frame sharepoint it works normal.

[image]

I'm from Brazil, is in Portuguese.

Comment: Can you edit your question an show the code? thank you

Comment: Has no code, I am doing natively.

Comment: can you post the uls log?

Comment: The log has 990 lines and says the error. Simply of this error there.

Comment: I pretty sure that you can find more on the uls log.

Comment: Already checked the log but have nothing conclusive.